# The gap between two inline-block <span> element

Tags: css

I created two  elements together in html and made each an inline-block. I found that there was always a gap between these two elements but actually I didn't set any padding/margin attibutes for them. Could someone tell me why and how I can fix this gap?

Comment: If there's any white-space at all between the two elements that white-space will collapse into a single space, per the spec.

Comment: Have you got the code? Maybe a JS fiddle? You should really accept answers to some of your questions too, it puts people off answering :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

CSS:

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span>This will have</span>
<span>a gap between the elements</span>

<span>This won't have</span><span>a gap between the elements</span>
```

Comment: Thans, man. This is the easist way to fix it for me.

Answer (score 19):

You can remove whitespace and keep nice code formatting using HTML comments.

```html
   <span>1</span><!--
--><span>2</span><!--
--><span>3</span>
```

Answer (score 12):

when you use `inline-blocks`, to remove the margin just apply `word-spacing: -3px;` and `letter-spacing: -3px;` to the **parent container** and then revert  these rules on inline-block elements with `word-spacing: normal;` and `letter-spacing: normal;`

e.g. with this basic markup

```
<div>
   <span>...</span>
   <span>...</span>
   <span>...</span>
</div>
```

the minimal CSS code is

```
div {
   word-spacing: -3px;
   letter-spacing: -3px;
}

span {
   word-spacing: normal;
   letter-spacing: normal;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Another possibility (that I don't recommend but it could useful for you to know, anyway) is to set `font-size: 0;` to the parent container.

Comment: Very tricky!!! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This is a weird behavior, which can be fixed, changed your markup to something like this.

```
<div class="inline">
   first
</div><div class="inline">
   second
</div>
```

Do not put any space, when defining another inline element.

Comment: They need to implement `white-space-collapse: discard;`!