# CSS: fix dt-dd margin

Tags: css, margin

When I place a **dt** and his **dd** element in one line:

```
display: inline-block;
margin: 0px;
```

There will still be a little margin between those two.
A solution I've found is:

```
margin-left: -4px;
```

But isn't there a better way to solve it?

Comment: very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207992/the-gap-between-two-inline-block-span-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the space is caused because an **inline-**block is part of the inline flow, which means any line break will cause a space. There are several solutions:

- Remove the newline between the two elements.
- Set `font-size: 0` on some common parent.
- Use floats instead of inline-block

**[Here's a good article on the subject.](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)**

Comment: Thanks! And is my solution (the margin-left) an acceptable solution or is it not-done?

Comment: It is, I haven't listed it because you are already using it :)

Comment: Margin-left:4px might not look right in all browsers, so be wary if you stick with it. If you do, make a separate css class for it.

Comment: Setting `margin-left: -4px` works in typical situations, but it’s just a guess and may go wrong. It is meant to nullify the effect of a space, but the width of a space varies (by font size *and* by font family). So removing newline is safer.