# Extra css padding or margin on graph

Tags: html, css

Really simple, im trying to make a bar graph. I have 10 items with 6.2% width and 2% padding either side apart from on the first and last. This should equal 100% bit it still pushes the last one over the edge, what have I done wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/7vdLV/4/

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.graph {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}
.weekbar {
    width: 6.4%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #aeaeae;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.start {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.end {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me @davidkonrad

Comment: yeah, sry - I dont know why it seemed ok, but depends on the width - and it gives less than 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `display: inline-block;` to `.weekbar` which adds a gap between the blocks. This is the default action. To remove the gap add `font-size:0;` to `.graph`

Check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/nkENR/)

Answer (score 1):

You may probably think about using float insteed of inline-block elements. there will always be a distance between inline-block elements difficult to control, specially if you are using %.

you can read more about this (and possible solutions) here:

[The gap between two inline-block <span> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207992/the-gap-between-two-inline-block-span-element)

[How do I remove extra margin space generated by inline blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801589/how-do-i-remove-extra-margin-space-generated-by-inline-blocks)

[How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using `display: inline-block;` If you got white space in your HTML, you get white space in your front end. Delete the white spaces in your HTML.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/7vdLV/23/